# MYSQL database to JSON format using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to convert get data from mysql in json format. For that I am using PHP.

My PHP code is

```
<?php 
define('_HOST_NAME', 'localhost');
define('_DATABASE_USER_NAME', 'root');
define('_DATABASE_PASSWORD', 'admin321');
define('_DATABASE_NAME', 'tree');

 $dbConnection = new mysqli(_HOST_NAME, 
     _DATABASE_USER_NAME, _DATABASE_PASSWORD, _DATABASE_NAME);

 if ($dbConnection->connect_error) {
      trigger_error('Connection 
      Failed: '  . $dbConnection->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
 }

 $_GLOBAL['dbConnection'] = $dbConnection;
    $categoryList = categoryParentChildTree(); 
    foreach($categoryList as $key => $value){
        echo $value['name'].'<br>';
 }

 function categoryParentChildTree($parent = 0, 
     $spacing = '', $category_tree_array = '') {
     global $dbConnection;
     $parent = $dbConnection->real_escape_string($parent);

 if (!is_array($category_tree_array))
    $category_tree_array = array();

 $sqlCategory = "SELECT id,name,parent FROM php WHERE parent = $parent ORDER BY id ASC";

 $resCategory=$dbConnection->query($sqlCategory);

 if ($resCategory->num_rows != null && $resCategory->num_rows>0) {

    while($rowCategories = $resCategory->fetch_assoc()) {
        $category_tree_array[] = array("id" => $rowCategories['id'],  "name" => $spacing . $rowCategories['name']);
        $category_tree_array = categoryParentChildTree(       
           $rowCategories['id'], 
           '&nbsp;'.$spacing . '-&nbsp;',  
           $category_tree_array
        );
    }
 }

 return  $category_tree_array;
}
?>
```

mysql table

```
      ID  PARENT  NAME
       1    0   category
       2    1   fruit
       3    2   apple
       4    2   orange
       5    1   animals
       6    5   tiger
       7    5   lion
       8    1   car
```

My output is:

```
  category 
       - fruit
         - - apple
         - - orange
       - animal
         - - tiger
         - - lion
       - cars
```

I want to get nested json output. Already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800408/php-array-to-nested-json-format). No proper response.

I tried with json_encode, not getting nested json.

UPDATED PHP

```
   <?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin321","tree");       

     if (mysqli_connect_errno())                     //con error
       {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
      $r = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM php ");
    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
     $data[] = $row;
     }  
     function buildtree($src_arr, $parent_id = 0, $tree = array())
 {
foreach($src_arr as $idx => $row)
{
    if($row['parent'] == $parent_id)
    {
        foreach($row as $k => $v)
            $tree[$row['id']][$k] = $v;
        unset($src_arr[$idx]);
        $tree[$row['id']]['children'] = buildtree($src_arr, $row['id']);
    }
}
ksort($tree);
return $tree;
}

     function insertIntoNestedArray(&$array, $searchItem){
// Insert root element
if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
    array_push($array, $searchItem);
    return;
}
if(empty($array)){ return; }
  array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
        array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
        return;
    }
    insertIntoNestedArray($item['children'], $searchItem);
     }, $searchItem);
   }
     $nestedArray = array();
   foreach($data as $itemData){
// First: Mount the nested array item
$nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['id'];
$nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['name'];
$nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['parent'];
$nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();

// Second: insert the item into the nested array
insertIntoNestedArray($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
      }
  $json = json_encode($nestedArray);
  echo $json;

  ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP array to Nested JSON format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800408/php-array-to-nested-json-format)

Comment: @YIVI i mentioned that  in the question..plz go thro it..

Comment: Asking the same question twice is not good, it just adds noise. If you are not getting responses, work on your question.

Comment: previous question updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your Nested Output is just an human-representation of the stored data you have in your database. Its a human thing. Machines can't understand that, that's why in mysql you need a column to tell the category parent.

So, your problem is that you're trying to convert to JSON your already manipulated data. You need to convert to JSON your raw data, and then manipulate it in the code that receives the JSON.

use json_encode to encode the raw data:

```
$raw_data = $resCategory->fetch_all();
return json_encode($raw_data);
```

Also, just a note: this `$_GLOBAL` variable you're using... you're not trying to refer to the internal php `$GLOBALS` superglobal, you are?

---

### EDIT:

Ok, now that you explained that you need the nested json format, you will need to use some recursion to build an nested array of arrays and then use the `json_encode` on it.

**First**: Get the raw data:

```
$resCategory=$dbConnection->query($sqlCategory);
$raw_data = $resCategory->fetch_all();
```

Now, suppose this `$raw_data` variable returns an array like this:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'ID' => 1,
    'PARENT' => 0,
    'NAME' => 'category',
  ),
  1 => array (
    'ID' => 2,
    'PARENT' => 1,
    'NAME' => 'fruit',
  ),
  2 => array (
    'ID' => 3,
    'PARENT' => 2,
    'NAME' => 'apple',
  ),
  3 => array (
    'ID' => 4,
    'PARENT' => 2,
    'NAME' => 'orange',
  ),
  4 => array (
    'ID' => 5,
    'PARENT' => 1,
    'NAME' => 'animals',
  ),
  5 => array (
    'ID' => 6,
    'PARENT' => 5,
    'NAME' => 'tiger',
  ),
  6 => array (
    'ID' => 7,
    'PARENT' => 5,
    'NAME' => 'lion',
  ),
  7 => array (
    'ID' => 8,
    'PARENT' => 1,
    'NAME' => 'car',
  )
)
```

**Second**: Build up an recursive function to insert items of this array into another array, the `$nestedArray` (that we will create in the third step).

```
function insertIntoNestedArray(&$array, $searchItem){
    // Insert root element
    if($searchItem['parent'] == 0){
        array_push($array, $searchItem);
        return;
    }

    // Stop the recursion when the array to check is empty
    if(empty($array)){ return; }

    // Walk the array searching for the parent of the search item
    array_walk($array, function(&$item, $key, $searchItem){
        // If the parent is found, then append the search item to it
        if($item['id'] == $searchItem['parent']){
            array_push($item['children'], $searchItem);
            return;
        }

        // If the parent wasn't found, walk thought the children of the array
        insertIntoNestedArray($item['children'], $searchItem);

    }, $searchItem);
}
```

**Third**: Create the `$nestedArray` and populate it by loop through the `$raw_data` array and calling the recursive function:

```
$nestedArray = array();
foreach($data as $itemData){
    // First: Mount the nested array item
    $nestedArrayItem['id'] = $itemData['ID'];
    $nestedArrayItem['name'] = $itemData['NAME'];
    $nestedArrayItem['parent'] = $itemData['PARENT'];
    $nestedArrayItem['children'] = array();

    // Second: insert the item into the nested array
    insertIntoNestedArray($nestedArray, $nestedArrayItem);
}
```

**Fourth**: Now its just to `json_encode` the `$nestedArray`:

```
$json = json_encode($nestedArray);
```

You can do an echo `$json` and the result will be:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"category","parent":0,"children":[{"id":2,"name":"fruit","parent":1,"children":[{"id":3,"name":"apple","parent":2,"children":[]},{"id":4,"name":"orange","parent":2,"children":[]}]},{"id":5,"name":"animals","parent":1,"children":[{"id":6,"name":"tiger","parent":5,"children":[]},{"id":7,"name":"lion","parent":5,"children":[]}]},{"id":8,"name":"car","parent":1,"children":[]}]}]
```

Comment: @programmer Sure, but can you create an question with your doubt?

Comment: thanks @leo ..i created the question with complete details here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222213/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input

Answer (score 0):

Simply this: `json_encode($output , JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: thanks for ur response sir..but output is   Fatal error: Uncaught Error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php(33): categoryParentChildTree('2', '&nbsp;&nbsp;-&n...', '{"0":{"id":"1",...') #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php(33): categoryParentChildTree('1', '&nbsp;-&nbsp;', Array) #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php(17): categoryParentChildTree() #3 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 32

Comment: @programmer it looks like thats another error. Can you show me whats on line 32?

Comment: very sorry sir,now i dont have code with me..when i reach office tomorrow i will immediately shows the line

Comment: here it is       $category_tree_array[] = array("id" => $rowCategories['id'], "name" => $spacing . $rowCategories['name']);       //line 32

Comment: have you tried to print the $rowCategories variable?

Comment: no..i used  $category_tree_array....                                                        return json_encode($category_tree_array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

Comment: i got the output ...thank you so much for your help sir